# GFCI Failures when not powered during cold weather

Tags: gfci, freezing

Does anyone know if GFCI failures are common when they are not powered during cold temperatures?

We have an outdoor GFCI outlet in a yard in front of our house. The outlet is controlled by a switch in the garage, and is off most of time (the outlet is used to power Christmas lights). We have noticed these past two years when we set up the Christmas lights that the GFCI has failed. I'm wondering if this is because the outlet is unpowered for most of the year, during times when the temperature can be at or below freezing.

It wouldn't be a big deal to leave it powered year round. We started turning it off when not needed because the outlet is too prominent and many years ago, during a flood, a neighbor from a low-lying area parked a travel trailer in front of the house and helped themselves to our electricity. We did get a freshly baked pie out of the deal, however[image]

Comment: Most likely it fails because it is exposed to the elements.  Using a good quality weatherproof cover can allow the outlet to last more than a year.

Comment: An outdoor outlet needs GFCI protection, but the protection does not need to be outside.  A GFCI device(on the circuit) inside the garage or a GCFI breaker will last longer and protect the outlet

Comment: Depends on your wiring. It it is a switch loop then best to put in a weather resistant box and a better quality outdoor GFCI. But if it is not a switch loop (i.e., if power and neutral both go to switch box and then to the GFCI/receptacle) better to replace the switch with a GFCI deadfront (and use that as a switch) or a switch-rated GFCI/receptacle. **Please upload pictures of the wiring in the switch box and GFCI box.**

Comment: I thought I used a good quality GFCI and it is in a good weatherproof box with an in-use cover. I had considered replacing switch with GFCI deadfront, but that won't work. See drawing. It does not show the neutral to the switch in garage. The neutral from the junction box in garage to outlet box in semi-circle (yard), serves both the outlet and two post lights, so putting GFCI in garage won't work, unless I install a second neutral in conduit from garage to yard outlet. There may be room to do that, but I would need to replace all conduit wires at same time.